# Count the lines of a file

Tags: java, lines, file-handling

I have a question about Java:

I am trying to make a program that goes through files and checks something, but for that I need something to count the lines, does anyone knows a good method to do this?

I have never worked with files before so I dont really know something.
Also I don't have code to show, because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: inform yourself about java IO streams https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By searching on the Internet you could have found this by yourself.
But nevertheless, here is a code that I use:

```
    public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        try {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int readChars = 0;
            boolean empty = true;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
                empty = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\n') {
                        ++count;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
        } 
        finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

I hope it works for you.

**Update:**

This should be easier for you.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
int lines = 0;
while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
reader.close();
System.out.println(lines);
```

Comment: Well, that was really fast, thank you! It seems to work (testet it shortly in the main method).

Comment: This is a really poor and convoluted way to count lines. I'd imagine doing something like this back when I was writing Java 1.2, but even then I'd use a `BufferedReader`. The only advantage here is that you can't break it with long lines (I'm talking 2GB or so), but that's rarely an issue.

Comment: @Kayaman Still it works so I'm going to use it, I will test both methods but both seem to be right :D

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah I know that this method is old but I still use it, don't ask me why its just preferred by me

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

```
long lineCount = 0;

try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))){
    lineCount = lines.count();
} catch (final IOException i) {
    // Handle exception.
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I dont want to use Java 8, because it isn't used that often yet :D

Comment: `Files.lines()` should be opened in a try-with-resources statement!

Comment: @Dogyman Java 8 is seeing very rapid adoption; you'd better get used to it very soon!

Comment: @fge That is very true! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, in lines variable you will get number of lines.

```
 public String getFileStream(final String inputFile) {
            int lines = 0;
            Scanner s = null;

            try {
                s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile)));
                while (s.hasNext()) {
                   lines++;
                }
            } catch (final IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (s != null) {
                    s.close();
                }
            }
            return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do this :-

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILEPATH));
        int lineCount = 0;
        while(br.readLine() != null)
            lineCount++;
        System.out.println(lineCount);
```

`BufferedReader` class provides `readLine()` which reads the text line-by-line so this can be used to get the lines count.

Answer (score 0):

you can do simply :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int linecount = 0;

    try {
        // Open the file
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("d:\\data.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fstream));
        String strLine;
        // Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (strLine.trim().length() > 0) { // check for blank line
                linecount++;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total no. of lines = " + linecount);
        // Close the input stream
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```